# How to use chromium engine inside google chrome to render my application

Tags: wpf, google-chrome, chromium, chromium-embedded

I wonder if it is possible to use chromium engine inside google chrome or the google chrome itself to render a web page inside my WPF application instead of using traditional WebView (because it's the IE engine and it's awful -_-) or implementing CEFSharp (because it uses about 200 MB of space only for the chromium engine)

so in this case I need the target pc to has installed google chrome or any other(firefox or ...)

Soooo ... is there any solution?

thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**

I want to create applications based on web UI, - because of being easy and powerful - I know some providing this feature, e.g. `CEF Sharp WPF` or `electron js` but they include a full chromium engine with the app. I don't want this.

I want to create my app as light as possible, and my idea is to use chromium engine of a modern browser, that almost everyone has one.

For example, imagine that the user has installed google chrome.

- first I locate the installation folder
- I use `chromium.exe -render path/to/file.html`(*imaginary*) command to render my application UI.
- finally bind the UI events to my native code. (e.g. c#(*wpf*) or any language that you can create desktop apps with it)

One solution is creating web apps by installing a website with the browser. but with that you cannot for example create or read some files in user pc, or any similar operation.

## I'm looking for the most light-weight solution...

Comment: FYI Google Chrome is based on Chromium

Comment: @Asesh sorry but I can't understand you. Could you please describe more?

Comment: @Asesh please see the edit

Comment: Depending on timescales etc I would consider blazor desktop.

Comment: create web application instead of wpf app

Comment: @ASh but then I don't have access to read/write file or similar operations that are not available via browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the right thing I want!

That's it!

## [webui](https://github.com/webui-dev/webui)!

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Chromium based `WebView2` control that you can use to embed modern web content in your WPF application.

Please refer to the docs for more information about the prerequisites and how to use it:

[Getting started with WebView2 in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf)

Comment: So, cool. but some problems. everywhere I saw, they said install Runtime OR edge **CANARY** channel. so why canary channel??

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

So, let's say that you want your UI to be rendered in a chromium environment(aka a browser)… right?

let's take a look at **electron js**:

- it uses NodeJS as backend.
- it uses an **embedded browser** for frontend.
- the language used is JavaScript due to NodeJS.

So, you want to use the client's browser to render your frontend instead of embedding a browser inside it.

well, don't embed it!!

you can create a web application(e.g. opened by typing *localhost:<port>* in browser<sup>1</sup>) using NodeJS and handle your IPC(between frontend and backend) using ajax calls or a socket connection.

that way you are doing exactly what an electron app does, except that, electron uses a bundled browser.

now you made your app lighter, also if your client do have NodeJS installed, you don't need to bundle NodeJS!

--- ***inspired by jupyter notebooks*** ---

### Possible Solutions

1. use NodeJS as backend.
2. use python and combine it with Flask or Django as backend. *(I think this would be the most lightweight solution)*
3. use PHP as backend. *(the best, personal opinion)*
4. use ASP.NET/Blazor as backend. *(as mentioned in the comments; but doesn't seem to be a lightweight solution)*
5. or use any language that you can create a web application with that!

---

1. make a `runApp.bat` or `runApp.sh` to simply run your server and open the browser automatically.